# Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field GMAIL API

Tags: javascript, json, docker, gmail, gcloud

I'm trying to get my gmail API all setup and working but I'm getting this error: `Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field`. I created the proper credentials from the GCS console and downloaded the JSON file, put the path to it inside an ENV variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json` (I'm keeping my json file in root). My file looks like this:

```json
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "<id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "<name>",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "<client_secret>",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost"]
  }
}
```

Which is why the error confuses me because google didn't provide a `client_email` field. I looked at some other possible answers and one said to create an email from a service account. I did that and updated my JSON file to add this line `"client_email": "<service_account_name>@<project_name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`
And I'm still getting the error.

I can't auth from the gcloud CLI tool either because I'm running this on docker so it doesn't have access to the root folders of my mac.

Here is the full error:

```
slots-api       | node:events:491
slots-api       |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
slots-api       |       ^
slots-api       |
slots-api       | Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field
slots-api       |     at JWT.fromJSON (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:210:19)
slots-api       |     at GoogleAuth._cacheClientFromJSON (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:410:20)
slots-api       |     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:446:40)
slots-api       |     at ReadStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
slots-api       |     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
slots-api       |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
slots-api       | Emitted 'error' event on Subscription instance at:
slots-api       |     at Subscriber.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/subscription.js:253:38)
slots-api       |     at Subscriber.emit (node:events:513:28)
slots-api       |     at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/subscriber.js:545:38)
slots-api       |     at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
slots-api       |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
slots-api       |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
slots-api       |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
slots-api       | error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: You are trying to use an OAuth client for an **installed** application which is used to authenticate users. You should be specifying a Service Account JSON Key file.

Comment: @JohnHanley You're right, that worked! I can't express how happy I am to have this bug out of my way. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnHanley this would be in a separate answer, That is the final and effective solution that the majority of the documentation and tutorial forget!